# How to transfer this code with JQuery Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hope you can help me, I recently was told it would suit me best was to use Ajax with JQuery.
The trouble is that this code programmed it long ago and following tutorials.
I tried to pass the JQuery format but does not work in any way, do not know if some kind soul can guide me how to do it.

The code is as follows:

These functions define three parameters and sends them to another function called "get_ajax":

```
function resultado(contenido){
    var url='ajax/buscar.php?'+ contenido +'';// Get content
    var capa='resultado';
    var metodo='get';
    get_ajax(url,capa,metodo);
}
function paginas(contenido){
    var url='ajax/paginar.php?'+ contenido +'';// Get pages
    var capa='paginas';
    var metodo='get';
    get_ajax(url,capa,metodo);
}
```

Then created the Ajax object:

```
function creaAjax(){
    var objetoAjax=false;
    try{objetoAjax = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");}
    catch(e){try {objetoAjax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");} 
    catch (E){objetoAjax = false;}}
    if(!objetoAjax && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
        objetoAjax = new XMLHttpRequest();}
    return objetoAjax;
}
```

And finally defined "get_ajax" function with the variables defined in the "result" functions and "pages":

```
function get_ajax(url,capa,metodo){ 
    var ajax=creaAjax();
    var capaContenedora = document.getElementById(capa);
    if (metodo.toUpperCase()=='GET'){
        ajax.open ('GET', url, true);
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (ajax.readyState==1){
                capaContenedora.innerHTML= "<center><img src=\"imagenes/down.gif\" /><br><font color='000000'><b>Loading...</b></font></center>";
            } else if (ajax.readyState==4){ 
                if(ajax.status==200){               
                    document.getElementById(capa).innerHTML=ajax.responseText; 
                }else if(ajax.status==404){
                    capaContenedora.innerHTML = "<CENTER><H2><B>ERROR 404</B></H2>0 RESULTS</CENTER>";
                } else {
                    capaContenedora.innerHTML = "Error: ".ajax.status;
                }
            } // ****
        }
        ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        ajax.send(null);
        return
    }
}
```

The results of carrying on a "div" calling a javascript:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" name="resultado" id="resultado">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            resultado('q=<?=$q?>&p=<?=$p?>');
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I think this last one is the least.
I've been trying to change the "get_ajax" function to make it to corde a JQuery syntax pero it does not work.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
I tried changing the "get ajax" function, I know that the code you are totally wrong, but I have almost no experience with JQuery, I read the manual and know that for each state there is a different role, but this time I wanted to test directly with "success ".

```
function get_ajax(url,capa,metodo){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#resultado').hide();
        $('#form').submit(function(evento){
            $('#resultado').hide();        
            evento.preventDefault();
            var datos_formulario = $(this).serialize();        
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: datos_formulario, //I don't know
                type: metodo,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response){
                    $(capa).html(response);
                }
            });

        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Please show what you have as the attempt to use the jQuery way. [Examples of using jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#entry-examples)

Comment: You should add the code you tried, the code that does not work

Comment: Thanks for commenting, I've updated the post, my code makes me laugh but I think I get the idea, right?

Comment: Try it without the $(document).ready. If you need to hide the element just put it outside your get_ajax function with the $(document).ready.

Comment: the dataType is the response type so you might want to change that to html or text.